# PHP: Найти значений в массиве $array2['login'] по ключу $array1['login'] из другого массива и записать в новый $result

Tags: php

Коллеги!
Подскажите как реализовать  поиск по массиву $array2 ключем $array1['login'] из другого массива? Я с PHP не глубоко знаком, и задачка для меня сложная. 
Нужно создать массив с пользователями которые есть в обоих массивах и массив в котором нет пользователей в $array1.

```
<?php


$array1 = array (
    array (
    "Name" => "Иван Иванович",
    "login" => "IvanIv",
    "mail" => "ivan@mail"
),
    array (
   "Name" => "Степан",
    "login" => "Stepan",
    "mail" => "stepan@mail.ru"
    )
);

$array2 = array (
    array (
        "Name" => "Иванов",
        "login" => "ivanov",
        "type" => "3"
),
    array (
        "Name" => "Степан",
        "login" => "Stepan",
        "type" => "3"
    ),
    array (

        "Name" => "",
        "login" => "petrov",
        "type" => "1"
    ),
    array (
        "Name" => "",
        "login" => "TechAccount",
        "type" => "3"
    )
);
```

Я представляю что сначала должен быть, но не уверен:

```
   for ($i=0; $i < $array2["login"]; $i++){
foreach ($array2 as $k => $v) {
    if ($v[$i]["login"]=$v) {
        $newArray[] = [
            'Name' => $update["Name"][0],
            'login' => $update["login"][0],
            'mail' => $update["mail"][0],
```

Только не знаю как правильно сравнить значения $array2[$i]["login"] и $array1[$i]["login"]

Заранее благодарю.
И буду очень благодарен за любую помощь.

Может даже так?:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $array1["count"]; $i++)
$login = $array1["login"];
for ($i=0; $i < $array2["count"]; $i++){
    foreach ($array2 as $k => $v) {
        if ($v[$i]["login"]=$login) {
            $newArray[] = [
                'Name' => $update["Name"][0],
                'login' => $update["login"][0],
                'mail' => $update["mail"][0],
}
    }
};
```

Написал но почему то не работает.

```
$newArray = [];
for ($i=0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
        $login = $array1[$i]["login"];
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($array2); $i++) {
            foreach ($array2 as $k => $v) {
                if (strpos($k, "login") == $login) {
                    $newArray[] = [
                        'Name' => $v["Name"][0],
                        'login' => $v["login"][0],
                        'mail' => $v["mail"][0],
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo '<h3>Dump $newArray:</h3><pre>';
    print_r($newArray);
    echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: чего на выходе от ожидаете от этих двух массивов?

Comment: Нужен массив с пользователями которые отсутствуют в $array2

Comment: у вас в 1 массиве нет таких, которые отсутствуют во втором

Comment: А как же IvanIv - его нет во втором

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться двумя функциями - array_column, чтобы получить список логинов во втором массиве, и array_filter, чтобы отобрать нужные

```
$login2= array_column($array2, 'login');
$login2 = array_map('strtolower', $login2);
$res = array_filter($array1, function($x) use($login2) 
       { return ! in_array(strtolower($x['login']), $login2); });
```

Comment: Удивительно!!  Но это работает!  Большое вам спасибо!

Comment: Коллега, можно ли научить функцию быть не регистрозависимой??..

Comment: Я поправил ответ, что б был регистронезависимый

Comment: Огромное Спасибо! Благодарю Вас!  +100500  то что нужно!  Обязательно буду читать какие функции есть в языке.